# Java Scanner cannot find word

Tags: java, pattern-matching, java.util.scanner

I am sorry if there is something very simple I am missing.

I have the following code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
public class UnJumble
{
    String[] ws;
    int ind=0;
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println("Enter a jumbled word");
        String w = new Scanner(System.in).next();

        UnJumble uj = new UnJumble();
        uj.ws = new String[uj.fact(w.length())];
        uj.makeWords("",w);

        int c=1;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("dict.txt"));
        for(int i=0; i<uj.ws.length; i++)
        {
              Pattern pat = Pattern.compile(uj.ws[i].toUpperCase());
              if(sc.hasNext(pat))
                    System.out.println(c+++" : \'"+uj.ws[i]+"\'");
        }

        System.out.println("Search Completed.");
        if(c==1) System.out.println("No word found.");
    }

    public void makeWords(String p,String s)
    {
        if(s.length()==0)
              ws[ind++] = p;
        else
              for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++)
                    makeWords(p+s.charAt(i),s.substring(0,i)+s.substring(i+1));
    }

    public int fact(int n)
    {
        if(n==0) return 1;
        else return n*fact(n-1);
    }
}
```

The `dict.txt` file is the SOWPODS dictionary, which is the official Scrabble dictionary..

I want to take in a jumbled word, and rearrange it to check if it is present in the dictionary. If it is, then print it out.

When I try `tra` as input, the output says `No word Found.`.
But the output should have the words `tar`, `art` and `rat`.

Please tell me where I am making a mistake. I apologize if I have made a very simple mistake, because this is the first time I am working with `Pattern`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is from the JavaDoc of [`Scanner.hasNext(Pattern pattern)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext(java.util.regex.Pattern)) (with my highlighting)

> Returns true if the **next complete token** matches the specified pattern.

As your Scanner was initialized with file `dict.txt`, it is positioned **on first word**.

And the first complete token in dict.txt does not match any of your scambled words, so no match is found.

Note: This assumes you have one word per line

I'd think you may want to change your code to find your scrambled text *somewhere* in the dictionary file (with start-of-line before and end-of-line after) resulting in a pattern `"(^|\\W)"+uj.ws[i].toUpperCase()+"(\\W|$)"` and something like

```
 String dictstring = your dictionary as one string;

 Matcher m = p.matcher(dictstring);
 if(m.find()) {
  ...
```

I recommend [`IOUtils.toString()`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#toString(java.io.InputStream)) for reading your file like this:

```
String dictstring = "";
try(InputStream is = new FileInputStream("dict.txt")) {
  dictstring = IOUtils.toString(is);
}
```

Here's a small example code to get familiar with pattern and matcher:

```
    String dictString= "ONE\r\nTWO\r\nTHREE";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(^|\\W)TWO(\\W|$)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(dictString);
    if(m.find()) {
        System.out.println("MATCH: " + m.group());
    }
```

Comment: And should I use something like `while(sc.hasNext()) dictstring+= sc.next()` to take my whole dictionary as one string?

Comment: As you don't want matches inside words try the "(^|\\W)"+uj.ws[i].toUpperCase()+"(\\W|$)" regex once

Comment: Isn't that the same?

Comment: I think I lost track of what's uppercase and what not while editing. Check the example at the end and adjust to your code.

Comment: When I am using `while(sc.hasNext()) dictstring+= sc.next()+"\r\n"` to make the `dictstring` from my dictionary, it is taking **a lot** of time. Any other method?

Comment: see my code - `IOUtils.toString()` is the thing you'll need I'd guess.

Comment: It works.  But, won't creating a String of approx. (266751*6) characters be a burden on memory?

Comment: And wouldn't parsing a file line by line for each permutation of a word be a really heavy burden on runtime-performance? Your dict is some MB large in memory - even most smartphone would be able to handle that.

Comment: So, Is there no way by which we can scan such a file without burdening the memory?

Comment: Yes of cause - but this would slow it down. You can have it fast (in memory) or slow (on disk) or a mix of those by putting file into a database and selecting for match...

Comment: But What mistake have I made in my code in question?

Comment: sorry but have your read my answer? Scanner.hasNext(Pattern ) will only return true if the **next token** matches. Your code always matched against the first string in the file and **only** that first string.